# What is the purpose of the <Module> class?

Tags: c#, .net

When decompiling .NET assemblies, I notice that the compiler adds an empty internal class named `<Module>` on the global namespace. This class is not used from anywhere else in the assembly and its name is an illegal C# identifier.

What is this class and what is its purpose?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to §II.10.8 of the [CLI's Ecma specification](https://www.ecma-international.org/publications-and-standards/standards/ecma-335/), the `<Module>` class contains the assembly's *global fields and methods*.

C# does not have such concept, but this class is used by the .NET runtime to support [module initializers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/module-initializers).

Starting with C# 9.0, module initializers can be defined from code. This snippet:

```cs
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

public static class C {
    [ModuleInitializer]
    public static void M() {
    }
}
```

will compile to something like this:

```cs
internal class <Module>
{
    static <Module>()
    {
        C.M();
    }
}
public static class C
{
    // On frameworks earlier than .NET 5 you have to define the attribute yourself.
    [ModuleInitializer]
    public static void M()
    {
    }
}
```

`<Module>`'s static constructor will be executed once when the assembly gets loaded, and will call all methods decorated with `ModuleInitializerAttribute`.

As a sidenote, the `<Module>` class has no ancestor (its `BaseType` property is set to `null`); something to keep in mind when using reflection.